# Query based on dates to show what has not been done

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make sure communication gets sent out properly.
I have a list of emails in EmailMain that need to be sent to my team leaders a certain number of days before the team arrives. 
I want to make a reminder list or possibly a conditional formatting that will alert me that I need to send more emails.

I know that the query I included below is not right. I just added it as a starting point.

Tables Involved.

```
EmailLog
EmailLogID
EmailMainID
EmailDate
TeamDetailsID
```

```
EmailMain
EmailMainID
EmailSubject
AdvanceDays
```

```
TeamDetails
TeamDetailsID
ArriveDate
```

```
SELECT EmailMain.EmailMainID, EmailMain.AdvanceDays, EmailLog.SentDate, EmailLog.TeamDetailsID, TeamDetails.ArriveDate
FROM TeamDetails INNER JOIN (EmailMain RIGHT JOIN EmailLog ON EmailMain.EmailMainID = EmailLog.EmailMainID) ON TeamDetails.TeamDetailsID = EmailLog.TeamDetailsID
WHERE (((EmailLog.TeamDetailsID)=39))
ORDER BY EmailMain.AdvanceDays DESC;
```

Comment: Possibly `ArriveDate BETWEEN Date() AND DateAdd("d", AdvanceDays, Date())` or maybe `ArriveDate = DateAdd("d", AdvanceDays, Date())`.

Comment: Thanks I am working on implementing your idea. Trying to make a couple queries work together to get what I need to happen.